# Visual studio code is git pushing but repo does not match

Tags: git, visual-studio, ide, commit, git-commit

I can't figure this out

I normally do my github commits like so *(just using command prompt)*

command prompt → `cd` to the directory → `git add .` → `git commit -m "Commit Message"` → `git push origin master`

---

but,

When I run in visual studio code, and I make changes to my repo, I'll stage those items to commit

When I push it upstream and then create a git commit > push onto my repo, everything shows that it is successful

**HOWEVER,** when I go to my github repo, the commit is no where to be seen there nor are the changes there either

**ALSO,** when I run `git status` through my command prompt, it shows

> "nothing to commit, working tree clean"

indicating I did commit/push, but then again my github repo does not match this

---

I'm running git-scm , and the git history(git log) extension through visual studiocode

Could someone enlighten me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you do git-sync  ?

Comment: Did you commit push on master? What is the full and complete output of git status?

Comment: oh I forgot to `git push origin master` from the terminal, I assumed visual studio code was already doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to run the terminal `git push origin master`

Didn't realize I still had to do this with visual studio code. This video sums up how to setit up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuFky3vdWpo

Comment: On a side note, since I had already did git commit and git push from just the command prompt already, I didn't need to run `git remote add origin MY-REPO-URL` since it was in my /.git/config folder already

Comment: https://youtu.be/VOwyH2-VCVY?t=208 → actually nevermind you could push without terminal, theres buttons for this in visual studio code